# Issue with calculating probability from a binary logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

Response variable: detection/non-detection of voles, 0/1 data
Explanatory variable:survey events/day where predator present
number of days = 12
range of events = 13
Coefficients/logits = -1.145, -0.132
In order to convert this to the probability of response variable = 1 I was
 trying this:    P(vole detection=1) = p = (-1.145 - 0.132 * predator events)

My issue is what do I put for "predator events"
Would it be correct to put the range, 13?
I hope this data is enough to give an idea of what Im trying to do, please let me know if it isn't adequate

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You  put the number of predator events. You get a different estimate for each number of predator events.  If you want the overall probability then you don't need logistic regression, you can just take the number of voles detected divided by the number of voles.